# Show that the Cauchy distribution, whose density is $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\left[\pi\left(1+x^{2}\right)\right]}$ does not possess finite moments.

Tags: probability-distributions, cauchy-sequences, moment-generating-functions

This from Hoel's Statistical Book:
Show that the Cauchy distribution, whose density is $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\left[\pi\left(1+x^{2}\right)\right]}$ does not possess finite moments.

I've been reading the recommended section for this problem, but I have no clue of how to solve it.

Comment: Hint: For what values of the exponent $\alpha$ does $\int_a^\infty x^\alpha dx$ converge?

Comment: If a distribution does not have a $n$-th moment. It will not have any moment $m\ge  n$. Thus, it suffices to show that it does not have a finite expectancy.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_R\frac{|x^n|}{1+x^2}dx$ does not exist for $n\ge 1$, since integrand ~$x^{n-2}$ as $x\to \infty$.